# PHP + MySQL - Cannot update multiple table at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I got a php form to update MySQL tables. The fetch works perfectly but the updates are not working. This is my form code :

```
<?php

$sql= "SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName FROM client WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$sqlM= "SELECT menu.id AS mid, menu.name AS mname FROM menu WHERE menu.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
$rsM = mysql_query($sqlM) or die($sqlM."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$sqlF= "SELECT facilities.id AS fid, facilities.name AS fname FROM facilities WHERE facilities.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
$rsF = mysql_query($sqlF) or die($sqlF."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$sqlS= "SELECT services.id AS sid, services.name AS sname FROM services WHERE services.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
$rsS = mysql_query($sqlS) or die($sqlS."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

// $names array now contains all names

$i = 0;


echo '<table width="50%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>ID</td>';
echo '<td>Name</td>';
echo '<td>Edit</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo "<form name='form_update' method='post' action='client_admin_post.php'>\n";

while ($fm = mysql_fetch_array($rsM)) { // loop as long as there are more results
    $mnames[] = $fm['mname'];
    $mid[] = $fm['mid'];  // push to the array


echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Menu :</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='mname' value='{$fm['mname']}' /></td>";
echo "<td>{$fm['id']}<input type='hidden' name='mid' value='{$fm['mid']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;

print_r($mnames);
}

while ($ff = mysql_fetch_array($rsF)) { // loop as long as there are more results
    $fnames[] = $ff['fname'];
    $fid[] = $ff['fid'];  // push to the array


echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Facilities :</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='fname' value='{$ff['fname']}' /></td>";
echo "<td>{$ff['id']}<input type='hidden' name='fid' value='{$ff['fid']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;


}

while ($fs = mysql_fetch_array($rsS)) { // loop as long as there are more results
    $snames[] = $fs['sname'];
    $sid[] = $fs['sid'];  // push to the array


echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Services :</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='sname' value='{$fs['sname']}' /></td>";
echo "<td>{$fs['id']}<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='{$fs['sid']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;


}

echo'<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';



?>
```

This is my post code :

```
$size = count($_POST['mname']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
$mname= $_POST['mname'][$i];
$mid = $_POST['mid'][$i];


$query = "UPDATE menu SET name = '$mname' WHERE id = '$mid' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
echo "$mname<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
++$i;
}


$size = count($_POST['fname']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
$fname= $_POST['fname'][$i];
$fid = $_POST['fid'][$i];


$query1 = "UPDATE facilities SET name = '$fname' WHERE id = '$fid' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query1) or die ("Error in query: $query1");
echo "$fname<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
++$i;
}


$size = count($_POST['sname']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
$sname= $_POST['sname'][$i];
$sid = $_POST['sid'][$i];

$query3 = "UPDATE services SET name = '$sname' WHERE id = '$sid' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query3) or die ("Error in query: $query3");
echo "$sname<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
++$i;
}
```

I got 'updated' status in post page but nothing is updated in MySQL table. How to solve this problem? Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so that you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: I'm still a beginner and I'm still learning php. For sure if I want to build a permanent page, I'll use PDO or MySQLI. I'm still learning basic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating multiple inputs with the same name, such as "fname," but you're trying to access them as if they were an array. Rename the fields like the following:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='mname[]' value='name' /></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

too long question but if you but by update status in post page you mean to say it echoed update if i am right it will echo update since you are checking it in while and the condition is true. But have you echoed the posted values in post page check whether you are getting the value proceed this way to find where are you having problems before asking here long questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transacrions in mysql if you want all the queries should be executed otherwise none.

Your post page says updated because at the end of your queries you just echo "Updated", there is no condition when it should be printed.

and your data is not updated as you are not specifying any connection variable for mysql_query("query",$conn)

Comment: @Pé de Leão is right you are creating multiple inputs with same name you can use array like name=mname[], name=fname[], name=sname[]
and thn on post page iterate through array for each name using foreach loop.